# Magento 1.9.3 - "Warning: strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string" warnings

Tags: magento-1.9, php, upgrade

I'm seeing a lot of the following warnings after upgrading to 1.9.3.1 in the `system.log`:

```
"Warning: strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given  in ../app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Source/Table.php on line 79"
"Warning: strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given  in ../app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Source/Table.php on line 79"
"Warning: strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given  in ../app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Source/Table.php on line 79"
```

Also checked the affected Model already near line 79 it says..

```
...
70: /**
71:  * Get a text for option value
72:  *
73:  * @param string|integer $value
74:  * @return string
75:  */
76: public function getOptionText($value)
77: {
78:   $isMultiple = false;
79:    if (strpos($value, ',')) {  # <--- this line causes the warning...
80:        $isMultiple = true;
81:        $value = explode(',', $value);
82:    }
83:
84:    $options = $this->getAllOptions(false);
...
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: try to check `$value ` by if condition. that should not be blank

Comment: Is this code from "the affected Model" in a custom module, a third party extension or in the core?

Comment: I'm guessing there is a call to getOptionText that is being done from an extension that is causing you issue?  You could add some additional logging in there to dump the offending value and see if you can track it down?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the hints. I've successfully identified the problematic module `Official Ingenico ePayments Extension` and upgraded it. Now the issue is solved.